# Are administrative permissions for remote disabling of phone the same as root?

Tags: root-access, device-administrator, find-my-device

I have a Samsung Galaxy S3 with Android 4.3. If I choose the option for remote disabling the phone if the phone is lost or stolen, it asks for some administrative permissions.

Are these permissions the same as ROOT, i.e. after giving these permissions, will my phone be rooted?

Answer (score 4):

Administrative privileges are not the same as root. They allow for a slightly elevated level of security for controlling things like the lock screen or other tasks that most apps shouldn't have access to. Enabling administrative permission for an app won't void your warranty or anything. Just be careful what you allow to have this access. The security app will need this permission to be able to lock the device and delete data (if the app supports it).